# How to disable header on frontpage of rst2pdf document?

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I am generating some PDF's and I would like to disable the header on the frontpage. I know there are built-in templates in rst2pdf and one template is called `coverPage` but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

The manual is saying you should use a

```
..raw:: pdf  
  PageBreak coverPage
```

statement but that will insert a empty before the coverpage, so how can I have a coverpage without a header and without using the `oddeven` directive (I want to use the same header on all remaining pages).

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you change the stylesheet **after** the cover page. You'll need to create a custom stylesheet that specifies what is the format of the first page and then change the style for the rest of document. Have a look at chapter 15 of the [manual](http://ralsina.me/static/manual.pdf).

Comment: I fixed the broken link

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** current accepted answer contains broken link (linked website has gone).

The correct answer is simple:

1) In you style-file define:

```
pageSetup:
  firstTemplate: coverPage
```

2) Then in your template, when you want to start using header/footer add:

```
..raw:: pdf
  PageBreak cutePage
```

Make sure `cutePage` has set header/footer to `true`.